# selecting a row using radio button and passing the value using button in jquery &struts2

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, radio-button

I've to select a row of the grid using radio button and pass the value on click of "Next" button.

I'm using struts2

My jsp code contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

        $("#flowPathTable").jqGrid({
                jsonReader: { 
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "rowid",
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                },
                url: jqDataUrl,
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "POST",
        colNames:["","CityName"]
        colModel :[ name:'radioid', index:'radioid', width:'20%',align:'center', formatter: radio, editable:false, sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:"strCity", index:"strCity"}],
        loadonce: true,
        caption:"Select City"
        });
        });


    function radio(value, options, rowObject){
                var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" value=' + value + ' name="radioid"/>';
                return radioHtml;
    }

 <s:submit type="image" src="../../images/next.png" "/>
```

On click of the "next button" the value has to passed. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If all the radio button's name is "radioid" then you can access the selected value by

```
var selected = $("input[name='radioid']:checked").val();
```

Place this code on click of the next button

Comment: What if i've more 2 columns in the table. Right now i've the following code as onClick for buttonvar id = $("#flowPathTable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); if (id) { var ret = $("#flowPathTable").jqGrid('getRowData',id); ret.strCity;  This happens on row select.. Ideally i need the row to be selected onClick of the radio button

Comment: Not getting you. please clarify your question

Comment: When I selecct the row and then click on "Next" button(Note:I have selected the row not the radio button ) I've an onClick function for the "Next" button var id = $("#flowPathTable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
 var ret = $("#flowPathTable").jqGrid('getRowData',id); 
alert(ret.strCity) gives me the city of the row selected. But i want this to happen onClick of the radio button not the row